# Change column sort order in Power BI table based on selected slicer value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following result_table as data source:

[image: result_table]

What I would like to achieve is to have a table visual with a slicer, where users can select the discipline and then see the table sorted by the result column - showing the best result on the first place. In my case that would mean:

- if 100m is selected, the Result column should be ASC sorted, because the result type for this discipline is TIME meaning the smaller the value, the better the result

[image: 100m]

- if Long Jump is selected, the Result column should be DESC sorted, because the result type for this discipline is DISTANCE meaning the smaller the value, the better the result

[image: longjump]

I found a very similar solution [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sorting-based-on-a-slicer-values-selection/td-p/1119186), with one problem: defining all the slicer values one by one wouldn't be efficient - I have many disciplines. I'm rather thinking of using a disc_table where the result type is defined for each discipline and using this information while configuring the switch.

[image: disc_table]

However I don't really know how this should be coded in the measure or if this is the best solution at all.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

UPDATE: I just noticed I missed an important part here. The result_table has a hidden column that contains the time results converted into milliseconds and the distance results converted to centimeters. This is because some disciplines have a result in different format, e.g. for 1000m it will look like this: 2:55,55. So the result column is in a text data type, but the table is actually sorted by the ConvertedResult column and is hidden on the visual (zero width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, here the measure I used together with the reference table called "Disciplines".

```
Ranking = 
IF (
  LOOKUPVALUE(Disciplines[ResultType], Disciplines[Discipline],
    SELECTEDVALUE(Results[Discipline]))="T",RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Results),CALCULATE(SUM(Results[ConvertedResult])),,DESC),RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Results),CALCULATE(SUM(Results[ConvertedResult])),,ASC))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have many disciplines. I'm rather thinking of using a reference table where the result type is defined for each discipline and using this information while configuring the switch.

Yes.  You don't really need to think about this in terms of a slicer.  Just write a measure that generates the correct ordering.  Use the [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) function to reference the current value of the discipline table.

This ended up being a little more involved than I thought.  I think you want to construct on Order By Column.  But you have to switch Result to type text, and then hide "ResultSort" and make it the "Order By Column" for Result.

Diciplines:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQwyFXSUQrJzE1VitWJVvLJz0tX8CrNLQAKumQWlyTmJQMlYgE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Dicipline = _t, ResultType = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dicipline", type text}, {"ResultType", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

and Results:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQwyFXSUQoNdgSSlnqWZkqxOtFKPvl56QpepbkFcClTMwOwDFS9u1MQWL2FOYZ6iJSJEVB9LAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Dicipline = _t, Country = _t, Result = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dicipline", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Result", type number}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Dicipline"}, Diciplines, {"Dicipline"}, "Diciplines", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Diciplines" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Diciplines", {"ResultType"}, {"ResultType"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Diciplines", "ResultDirection", each if [ResultType] = "Time" then -1 else if [ResultType] = "Distance" then 1 else null, type number),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "ResultSort", each 1000000*[Result]*[ResultDirection], Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ResultType", "ResultDirection"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Result", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: Thanks David, can you give me some more details? What should be the measure, how does it "generate the correct order"? And where should i put that measure once ready, into the slicer? Sorry, I'm not really an expert in Power BI (yet:)

Comment: Sorry, I noticed I missed some important information. I updated the original post, can you please if this make the suggested resolution easier?

Answer (score 0):

With `DAX`

if you have the following table

```
| Discipline | Country | Result |
|------------|---------|--------|
| 100m       | USA     | 9.69   |
| LJ         | GBR     | 560    |
| 100m       | GBR     | 9.87   |
| LJ         | USA     | 420    |
```

and you have a slicer for `Discipline` and you want the measure to sort by `ASC` on LJ and `DESC` on 100m.

You can do that by following

```
_sum = SUM('fact'[Result])
_rank = 
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'fact'[Discipline] ) = "LJ", RANKX ( ALL ( 'fact'[Country] ), [_sum],, ASC ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'fact'[Discipline] ) = "100m", RANKX ( ALL ( 'fact'[Country] ), [_sum],, DESC )
)
```

Once done, bring all the measure to the viz and Sort by `_rank` and then `Sort Ascending`

[image: Solution]

[image: Solution]

If you do resort to `DAX` for this, you do need to write separate statements per Discipline inside `SWITCH` and you define the desired ranking sort order inside corresponding `RANKX`

Comment: Thanks, please check the update in the original post - I missed an important part.

Comment: With this, you need perform the aggregation on `Converted Results` instead of `Result` in `_sum`.

Comment: Okay, so I managed to do this by using the solution linked in my original post. However the question remains: instead of having all the disciplines hardcoded in the 'SWITCH' function, is there a way to use the reference table and the 'LOOKUP' function within the switch?

Comment: Through this, you are asking the DAX engine to generate a custom order of your aggregation through `RANKX`. That custom order is decided by the report writer and per discipline. Therefore, that needs to be explicitly mentioned by the writer in a Ternary operator like `SWITCH`. The magic happens inside `RANKX`. But I don't think you can pass on a string with the RANKX statement form a disconnected like `SWITCH (TRUE (),SELECTEDVALUE ( CAT[CAT]) = "LJ", MAX(CAT[Expression]),SELECTEDVALUE ( CAT[CAT] ) = "100m", MAX(CAT[Expression]))` and yet that Expression will evaluate.

Comment: Because as of now, there is no such thing as dynamic DAX like dynamic SQL; such as  `exec ('select 1 as col1, 2 as col2')` is same as `Select 1 as col1, 2 as col2 ` in TSQL.